# Is clone() in java shallow copy?

Tags: java, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Is `clone()` in java a shallow copy?

> Eventually this gets to the clone()
>   method of Object (the uppermost
>   class), which creates a new instance
>   of the same class as the object and
>   copies all the fields to the new
>   instance (a "shallow copy").

I read this from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy).

I don't understand why it is a shallow copy. `clone()` will create a new instance with all fields. Is this just a deep copy? confused. Need some explanation for me.

Comment: Among many other duplicates of this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175620/in-java-what-is-a-shallow-copy

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The default `Object.clone()` is indeed a shallow copy. However, it's designed to throw a `CloneNotSupportedException` unless your object implements `Cloneable`.

And when you implement `Cloneable`, you *should* override `clone()` to make it do a deep copy, by calling `clone()` on all fields that are themselves cloneable.

Comment: making clone deep or shallow is not a "should" or "should not" type of thing, it entirely depends on the intended usage.

Comment: @jtahlborn: It's indeed a "should" thing, in that others who call your `clone` will be expecting the behaviour as described. Of course, there are exceptions, such as for generic containers (@jt's answer). But in general, that's the expectation.

Comment: actually, considering all the containers use shallow clone, why would you claim that deep is the expectation?  (containers being the only mutable classes in the jdk which are cloneable, that i can think of).

Comment: for deep copy, you can serialize the object (in memory) and deserialize to a new object. it will be an exact clone (deep copy)

Answer (score 8):

It is a shallow copy because it only copies reference to other objects. Say we have these classes :

```
class A {
    B variable
    A() {
        variable = new B();
    }
}

class B { }
```

And now we make a clone of an instance of A :

```
A firstA = new A();
A secondA = firstA.clone();
```

The B instance in firstA and secondA will be the same. You won't have a copy of the B instance. This is why clone() is said to do shallow copy.

The diagrams on the page you linked should help you understand all that.

Answer (score 5):

As an aside, I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [Joshua Bloch's views on Cloneable](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

> If you've read the item about cloning
>   in my book, especially if you read
>   between the lines, you will know that
>   I think clone is deeply broken. There
>   are a few design flaws, the biggest of
>   which is that the Cloneable interface
>   does not have a clone method. And that
>   means it simply doesn't work: making
>   something Cloneable doesn't say
>   anything about what you can do with
>   it. Instead, it says something about
>   what it can do internally. It says
>   that if by calling super.clone
>   repeatedly it ends up calling Object's
>   clone method, this method will return
>   a field copy of the original.

Answer (score 4):

clone() creates copy of all fields.
Java have primitive types and refences - when you clone your object you get a new object with copies of all primitive field (it is like deep copy) but also you have copy of all refernce fields. So in result you get two objects with they own copies of primitives and copies of references to the same objects - both original and copied object will use the same objects.

Answer (score 3):

Some objects do not provide a deep copy. For example, an ArrayList will clone the list, but not the elements in the list. The following is from the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone%28%29) for ArrayList:

> ```
> public Object clone()
>
>     Returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance. (The elements themselves are not copied.)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation of Object.clone() is a shallow copy. This behavior is still useful for types that have a large number of primitive fields or Immutable fields. You can look at [How to properly override clone method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method) for how to properly override it. After calling super.clone(), then casting the resulting object, you can then clone deeper as needed.

Implicitly, the value of clone diminishes as the number of complex, mutable fields on your type increases.

Answer (score 1):

What `clone` does is defined for each object that chooses to support clone. Object.clone is protected, so no object allows clone unless someone has specifically defined it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But first you need that your class will implement Cloneable and throw exception

```
class A implements Cloneable{
    public int y;
    public B b;

    public A(){
        b = new B();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        A a = new A();
        A a2 = (A) a.clone();
        System.out.print(a.b==a2.b);
    }
}
```

Output: true