# How do I do a Java-deep copy of an object?

Tags: java, clone

I have a class (Literal). I need to be able to keep an intact Literal instance in memory throughout my application, and have a copy of it which I can alter. I have used two ways to do this:

1. class `Literal` implements `Cloneable` and override `Object.clone()` method.
2. Factory constructor:

   ```
   public Literal(Literal lit){
        this = lit;
   }
   ```

In both cases copying doesn't work. Every change I make to the copy, changes the original. Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you doing is only shallow copying.check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Comment: Are you sure that you work with Java? I am asking this because the second attempt with a *Factory constructor* (usually, this is called *copy constructor*) will result in a compile error "cannot assign a value to final variable this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use copy-constructor, then you will need to make a deep copy of every mutable member variable.

Say your Literal has member variables like this:

```
private String[] args;
private String s;
```

Then your copy-constructor would need to do something like this

```
public Literal(Literal l) {
  // have to deep copy the array, otherwise both instances are sharing the reference
  this.args = Arrays.copyOf(l.args, l.args.length);

  // safe to just copy the reference, String is immutable
  this.s = l.s;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. For how to say thank you, see [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 5):

since `Literal` is not a integral type, variables of type `Literal` holds a **reference** to the actual value, so `this = lit` just copies the reference, so your behavior.

You must copy all the member fields recursively to do a "real" copy.

This [article](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/) has been linked in the accepted answer to the question linked by Umesh in his comment, and I think it clears the conceptual problems you're hitting with your problem.

Comment: Actually I have and it still doesn't work.My actual constructor is public Literal(Literal lit){
  this.functor = lit.getFunctor();
  this.arguments = lit.getArguments();
  this.isCompound = lit.isCompound();
  this.isVarOrConst = lit.isVarOrConst();
  this.varOrconstName = lit.getVarOrconstName();
  this.arity = lit.getArity();
  this.subsumedBy = lit.getSubsumedBy();
  this.asString = lit.getLiteralAsString();
 }

Comment: you must do that **recursively**, since the same effect happens in the case your member fields are non-integral types.

Comment: Check out the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175620/in-java-what-is-a-shallow-copy

Comment: Οκ Ι did that, calling the constructor recursively from within itself. It works now. Thanks a lot!!