# shallow copy - new instance Or assignment

Tags: java

Shallow copy means a **"copy"** of an object with same values of their attributes whether primitive or reference values.

While performing shallow copy is it necessary to "*create a new instance*" ? as:

```
public class A {
    int aValue;
    B bObj;

    ...

    public A createShallow(A a1Obj) {
        A aObj = new A();
        aObj.aValue = a1Obj.aValue;
        aObj.bObj = a1Obj.bObj;

        return aObj;
    }
}
```

Or  copy *by assignment* is also considered as shallow copy:

```
B b = new B(10);
A a = new A(1, b);

A a1 = a;
```

This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) at wikipedia defines shallow copy as reference variables *sharing same memory block*. So according to this copy by assignment will also be a shallow copy.

But is not it a *variables pointing to same object* instead of *"copy"* of an Object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> While performing shallow copy is it necessary to "create a new
>   instance" ?

**Yes,** you must create an instance to create a copy (either `shallow` or `deep`) of your object. Just doing the assignment of reference just creates a `copy of reference` which points to the same instance.

You have used a `non-static method` that is creating a `copy`. But generally I prefer two ways: -

Either use a `copy-constructor`: -

```
public A(A obj) {
    copy.aValue = obj.aValue;
}
```

And use it like: -

```
A first = new A();
A copy = new A(first);
```

Or, use a `public static method` which takes an instance and returns a copy of that.

```
public static A createCopy(A obj) {
    A copy = new A();
    copy.aValue = obj.aValue;
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Why should you not use a non-static method for creating a copy? That sounds totally reasonable to me!

Comment: @akuhn. Yeah that is reasonable. It's all user preference. I prefer `copy constructor` or `static factory`. Well, I have edited that line of me. Thanks :)

Comment: `In shallow copy, you just copy the references and not primitives`- Sounds strange!. I think While copying we make copy of all the attributes which we want.

Comment: @aLearner.. That is why we have different types of copy. It's `Deep copy` that copies all the attributes. Not in `shallow copy`.

Comment: @aLearner. See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175620/in-java-what-is-a-shallow-copy

Comment: @aLearner.. Sorry, I read your example wrong. You are creating a `shallow copy` in your method. Yeah, in deep copy we don't copy the values of reference,rather we create a copy of each reference. That's why I wrote there earlier.

Comment: Anyways your answer is still nice and cleared some more points. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @aLearner. Umm. and you can ask for more clarification, if you still have any doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Assignment is not a copy - it's just a second reference to the same instance.

A *copy* must be a new instance, otherwise it isn't a copy; it's just another reference.

Answer (score 0):

> While performing shallow copy is it necessary to "create a new instance" ? as:

Yes, it is necessary.

> Or copy by assignment is also considered as shallow copy:

No, this is a totally different operation. There is no copy; this simply creates a new reference to the existing object. If you modify the object through this new reference, you are still modifying the original object.

Comment: Then it means at wiki definition of shallow copy is wrong and also at SO question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182565/java-deep-copy-shallow-copy-clone` example given by `Jay Elston` is wrong.

Comment: @aLearner: I think you're misreading the materials you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Reference assignment doesn't create a new object but just points to existing object.