# shallow copy of the array but not a copy of the reference

Tags: java

I stumbled upon a problem that I have to create a method which takes no input and return a shallow copy of the array(Not a copy of the reference) of MarketProduct of this Basket.

I know the solution is the following

```
public class Basket {
    private MarketProduct[] marketproducts;

    public Basket() {
        this.marketproducts = new MarketProduct[0];
    }

    public MarketProduct[] getProducts() {
        return this.marketproducts.clone();
```

what I don't understand is 
1. if it's shallow copy then it's a copy of the reference right? 2. can I use clone method to any object in java? does it copy the reference or the acutal object? if so then the following can be simplified right(instead of using for loop i can use clone?)?

```
public void add(MarketProduct input) {
        MarketProduct[] list = new MarketProduct[marketproducts.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < marketproducts.length; i++) {
            list[i] = marketproducts[i];
        }
        list[list.length-1] = input;
        this.marketproducts = list;
    }
```

Comment: No, you cannot just "clone()" any Java object. Yes, Java arrays implement interface [Cloneable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html), so you *can* clone them.  Your `Basket` has a reference to array `margetProducts`.  Each element in marketProducts has a reference to a `MarketProduct` object.  When you clone marketProducts, you *keep* the original references to the elements.  "clone" or a "for loop", both copy the *reference*.  Look [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/array/java-array-clone-shallow-copy/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175620/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. if it's shallow copy then it's a copy of the reference right?

No. It's a new array containing references to the same objects as the original array

> 2. can I use clone method to any object in java?

No. Read the javadoc of `Object.clone()` and `Cloneable` to know the rules.

> if so then the following can be simplified right(instead of using for loop i can use clone?)?

No, since `clone()` will give you a new array of the same length, and thus you won't be able to add a new element at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. if it's shallow copy then it's a copy of the reference right?

No, it's a new reference to a new object with copies of that object's properties. The details depend on the implementation of `clone`.

> 2. can I use clone method to any object in java? does it copy the reference or the acutal object?

First, `clone` isn't the right tool for a shallow copy of an array. You might use [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) instead. In your case, you'd allocate an array with room at the end for your new entry, then `arraycopy` the original into it, then add your entry.

```
public void add(MarketProduct input) {
    MarketProduct[] list = new MarketProduct[marketproducts.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(marketproducts, 0, list, 0, marketproducts.length);
    list[list.length-1] = input;
    this.marketproducts = list;
}
```

Obviously this is a bit expensive, you might look at using one of the `List` classes (perhaps `ArrayList`) so you don't grow the array each and every time.

Re `clone`, see [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()):

> Creates and returns a copy of this object.  The precise meaning
>    of "copy" may depend on the class of the object. The general
>    intent is that, for any object `x`, the expression:
>
> > ```
> >  x.clone() != x
> > ```
>
> will be true, and that the expression:
>
> > ```
> >  x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()
> > ```
>
> will be `true`, but these are not absolute requirements.
>    While it is typically the case that:
>
> > ```
> >  x.clone().equals(x)
> > ```
>
> will be `true`, this is not an absolute requirement.
>
> By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling
>    `super.clone`.  If a class and all of its superclasses (except
>    `Object`) obey this convention, it will be the case that
>    `x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()`.
>
> By convention, the object returned by this method should be independent
>    of this object (which is being cloned).  To achieve this independence,
>    it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the object returned
>    by `super.clone` before returning it.  Typically, this means
>    copying any mutable objects that comprise the internal "deep structure"
>    of the object being cloned and replacing the references to these
>    objects with references to the copies.  If a class contains only
>    primitive fields or references to immutable objects, then it is usually
>    the case that no fields in the object returned by `super.clone`
>    need to be modified.
>
> The method `clone` for class `Object` performs a
>    specific cloning operation. First, if the class of this object does
>    not implement the interface `Cloneable`, then a
>    `CloneNotSupportedException` is thrown. Note that all arrays
>    are considered to implement the interface `Cloneable` and that
>    the return type of the `clone` method of an array type `T[]`
>    is `T[]` where T is any reference or primitive type.
>    Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this
>    object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of
>    the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the
>    contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method
>    performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.
>
> The class `Object` does not itself implement the interface
>    `Cloneable`, so calling the `clone` method on an object
>    whose class is `Object` will result in throwing an
>    exception at run time.

So you can't use it on objets that don't implement `Cloneable`, but you can on objects that do.