# How to define a pointer in go, then pass this pointer in to a func to change its value?

Tags: pointers, go

```
import "fmt"

func zeroptr(ptr *int) {
    *ptr = 0
}

func main() {
    oneptr * int
    *ptr = 1
    fmt.Println("ptr is :", *ptr)
    zeroptr(ptr)
    fmt.Println("after calling zeroptr, the value of ptr is :", *ptr)
}
```

This does not work, I am looking for output as follows:

ptr is :1

after calling zeroptr, the value of ptr is : 0

Comment: Please indent your code. Your code is very hard to read like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your pointer point to? In order to manipulate the memory a pointer points to, you first need to point the pointer somewhere. Right now, your `ptr` is pointing to `nil` which is invalid. You could for instance do this:

```
func main() {
    var foo int
    var oneptr *int = &foo
    *oneptr = 1
    fmt.Println("oneptr is :", *oneptr)
    zeroptr(oneptr)
    fmt.Println("after calling zeroptr, the value of oneptr is :", *ptr)
}
```

For the future, please indent your code before submitting it here. You can do this with the `gofmt` program.

Answer (score 1):

You should use pass an &int to `zeroptr`, as in [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/_Lq5eFW8R-):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func zeroptr(ptr *int) {
    *ptr = 0
}

func main() {

    var ptr int
    ptr = 1
    fmt.Println("ptr is :", ptr)
    zeroptr(&ptr)
    fmt.Println("after calling zeroptr, the value of ptr is :", ptr)
}
```

Output:

```
ptr is : 1
after calling zeroptr, the value of ptr is : 0
```

You can see a similar example in "[What's the point of having pointers in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389064/6309)", from the [golang book](http://www.golang-book.com/8/index.htm).