# How to pass slice of struct as pointer to a function and modify it?

Tags: go

I have a slice of struct `[]student`, and I want to modify its content with function.

```
type student struct {
    name string
    age int
}

students := []student{
    {"Doraemon", 30},
    {"King Kong", 25},
}
```

Thus, I decided to pass it as a pointer. May I know how to pass the slice as a reference to a function?

```
func addAge (s *[]student) error { //this code has error
    //everyone add 2 years old
    for i, e := range *s {
        s[i].age = s[i].age + 2
    }
    //make the first student much older
    s[0].age = s[0].age + 5
    return nil
}
```

I keep playing with [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lHN-MBhtrX), but it gives many complains, such as

```
cannot range over s (type *[]student)
invalid operation: s[i] (type *[]student does not support indexing)
invalid indirect of s
...
```

How to precisely pass the reference of a `slice of struct` to a function? How to **range** the slice of struct? And how to **change** the value of the struct (modify the same struct in THE slice)?

I keep getting error while playing with `s *[]student`, `range *s`, `s []student`, `s *[]*student` ... so hard to get it correct...

*sorry for my NEWBIE question, still learning GO... trying hard*

Comment: Please show us the _exact code_ with your _exact_ error. It's hard to tell you how to improve your code when you have different, conflicting error messages.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to pass a pointer to a slice--slices are already passed by reference.

Comment: you **must** read that, https://blog.golang.org/slices. Slice is quiet special thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slices are passed by reference, so as long as you are modifying the existing slice content you should not explicitly pass a pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type student struct {
    name string
    age int
}

func main() {
    students := []student{
        {"Doraemon", 30},
        {"King Kong", 25},
    }

    err := addAge (students)

    fmt.Println(students)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }
}

func addAge (s []student) error {
    for i, _ := range s {
        s[i].age = 3
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now, for your `addAdditinalStudent` function you should actually use the [append](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15) function. Plus, have in mind

> ..., since the slice header is always updated by a call to
>   append, you need to save the returned slice after the call. In fact,
>   the compiler won't let you call append without saving the result.
>   [Slices#append](https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_10.)

```
// add student
students = append(students, student{"Test", 33})
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4xT_v3krbh)

Answer (score 2):

in Go you can pass items by value ([]student) or by reference ([]*student). When you want to operate on the values of a `struct{}` you should pass it to a function with its *reference* (the pointer).

So you can do something like this:

```
type student struct {
    name string
    age int
}

func addTwoYearsToAll(students []*student){
  for _, s := range students {
        s.age += 2
     }
}
```

This way you're working with the same exact items you build when appending to the slice. [Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/diFFLj0jmq).

Also take a look at [Are Golang function parameter passed as copy-on-write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995634/are-golang-function-parameter-passed-as-copy-on-write)