# Writing to a slice by a channel and a goroutine: why slice is eventually empty

Tags: go, goroutine

I run this function:

```golang
func Run() () {
    // This slice is going to be filled out by a channel and goroutine.
    vertices := make([]Vertex, 0)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Obtain a writer to fill out the vertices.
    writer := Writer(&wg, vertices)

    // Run an arbitrary logic to send data to writer.
    Logic(writer)

    // Stop the writer reading on the channel.
    close(writer)

    // Wait for the write to complete.
    wg.Wait()

    // See if vertices slice is actually filled out.
    DoublecheckVertices(vertices)
}
```

But eventually, my `vertices` slice is empty:

```golang
func DoublecheckVertices(vertices []Vertex) () {
    // Here I notice that `vertices` slice is actually empty :(

}
```

The function which returns the `writer` is something like this:

```golang
func Writer(wg *sync.WaitGroup, vertices []Vertex) (chan<- []*Triangle3) {
    // External code writes to this channel.
    // This goroutine reads the channel and writes to vertices.
    writer := make(chan []*Triangle3)

    // Write by a goroutine.
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        a := Vertex{}

        // Read from the channel and write them to vertices.
        for ts := range writer {
            for _, t := range ts {
                a.X = float32(t.V[0].X)
                a.Y = float32(t.V[0].Y)
                a.Z = float32(t.V[0].Z)
                vertices = append(vertices, a)
            }
        }
    }()

    return writer
}
```

Can anybody help me with figuring out why my `vertices` slice is eventually empty?

## Logs

Logs indicate that the `vertices` slice is actually filled out. But for some reason, it's empty when it's passed to `DoublecheckVertices`.

```golang
                vertices = append(vertices, a)
                // This Log shows the slice is actually filled out:
                fmt.Printf("vertices len() is %v\n", len(vertices))
```

Comment: I made sure that `Logic` is sending valid data to `writer`. So, `Logic` is bug free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems similar to "[Pass slice as function argument, and modify the original slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60628918/6309)"

If you want your goroutine to modify the slice you created outside, you would need a pointer to that slice:

```golang
func Writer(wg *sync.WaitGroup, vertices *[]Vertex) (chan<- []*Triangle3) {
    // External code writes to this channel.
    // This goroutine reads the channel and writes to vertices.
    writer := make(chan []*Triangle3)

    // Write by a goroutine.
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        a := Vertex{}

        // Read from the channel and write them to vertices.
        for ts := range writer {
            for _, t := range ts {
                a.X = float32(t.V[0].X)
                a.Y = float32(t.V[0].Y)
                a.Z = float32(t.V[0].Z)
                *vertices = append(*vertices, a)  <=====
            }
        }
    }()

    return writer
}
```

Comment: It's fixed. But I thought Golang would pass a slice by just a small header and its underlying data.

Comment: I thought that simply passing a slice would be enough, according to this, but I was wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/3405291

Comment: @user3405291 A slice, like everything else, is [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/6309). I suspect the `append(yourSlice, anElement)`, which recreates a slice with one more element, would change the value.

Comment: Right. Actually I didn't study [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/3405291) thoroughly, my bad: `If the function adds new elements to the slice, that requires changing the slice header, which the caller will not see.`

Comment: @user3405291 If your slice was pre-allocated with a known quantity of elements, *then* you might use `[]T` instead of `*[]T`: you would stored your `Vertex` in `vertices[0]` or `vertices [1]` or .... That should work.

Comment: Right, makes sense.