# A design question about Go's map and slice troubled me a lot

Tags: go, slice, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, go-map

Why does Go's slice has **'replication trap'**, but map does not?

Suppose we have a function that takes slice as an input parameter, and if slice is **expanded** in the function, only the copied slice structure is changed, instead of the original slice structure. The original slice still points to the original array, and the slice in the function has changed the array pointer because of the expansion.

```golang
func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2}
    fmt.Println(a) // [1 2]
    doslice(a)
    fmt.Println(a) // [1 2]
}

func doslice(a []int) {
    a = append(a, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    a[0] = 200
    fmt.Println(a) // [200 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
}
```

Look at the output, if slice is passed by 'reference', it won't be like [1 2].

```golang
func main() {
    mp := map[int]int{1:1,2:2}
    domap(mp)
    fmt.Println(mp) // map[1:1 2:2 3:3 4:4 ...], the same as below
}

func domap(mp map[int]int) {
    for i := 3; i < 100; i++ {
        mp[i] = i
    }
    fmt.Println(mp) // map[1:1 2:2 3:3 4:4 ...]
}
```

Look at this, the operation we've done in domap() worked!
Is it a trap?!
I mean, map is passed by 'reference'(*hmap) and slice is passed by 'value'(SliceHeader).
Why is it that map and slice are designed to be all inner referenced types and why is it so inconsistent?
Maybe it's just a design question, but why? Why slice and map like that?

Below is my guess about proving why `map` can only be passed by 'reference':

```
Assume that map is passed by value -> hmap struct type

(1) After Init: (hmap outside the function)
hmap.buckets = bucketA
hmap.oldbuckets = nil

(2) After passing the param, entering the function: (hmap inside the function)
hmap.buckets = bucketA
hmap.oldbuckets = nil

(3) After triggering the expanding: (hmap inside the function)
hmap.buckets = bucketB
hmap.oldbuckets = bucketA
```

But `slice` is **different**!

```
There is no incremental migration, 
and there is no oldbuckets, 
so you can use a structure because the function is isolated from the outside, 
whereas map is not, and oldbuckets are referenced outside the function.
```

I mean, the original purpose of this design may be **passing value**, to *prevent direct modification of the original variable in the function*, but map cannot be passed by value. Once the value is passed to the map, the original map data will be lost during the expansion of the function.

I will appreciate that if some one can help me solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

(I feel sorry for my poor Chinglish, I hope I described this well...:( It really troubled me a lot...)

Comment: Design questions are not well fit for SO. They are often opinion-based, and should be directed to the language authors.

Comment: Just remember that maps are actually pointers, while slices are structs holding a pointer. See [why slice values can sometimes go stale but never map values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520624/why-slice-values-can-sometimes-go-stale-but-never-map-values/55521138#55521138) This will make it easy to remember how they (should) behave.

Answer (score 0):

This was also [asked](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/Q7_Dj_ogVJE/m/C2-NkqIVBgAJ) on the golang-nuts mailing list, with this as part of the [reply](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/Q7_Dj_ogVJE/m/_5TSXCIaBgAJ) from Brian Candler:

> I think you have understood the issue well. From the source code at
> https://golang.org/src/runtime/slice.go :
>
> type slice struct {
> array unsafe.Pointer
> len   int
> cap   int }
>
> As you have found, this is passed by value.  You can of course pass a
> pointer to such a value explicitly, if you choose.
>
> > Is it a trap?!
>
> Well, it's something you have to learn about the language, but I think
> it's the best choice out of the design options which were available.
>
> Strings and slices are consistent with each other: they are plain
> structs, containing pointer to data, length, and (for slices)
> capacity.
>
> Could slices and strings have been implemented so that their value is
> always a *pointer* to a structure? I guess so, but I think you would
> still end up with a similar problem at a deeper level.  When you copy
> a slice (b := a), or pass it as a function argument, then you'd be
> copying a pointer, so you'd have two aliases to the same slice, and
> modifications to one would be visible to the other. But when you
> sub-slice (b := a[1:2]) then you'd be forced to allocate a new slice
> structure.  The behaviour of a slice therefore would be dependent on
> exactly how it was generated, and so mutating a slice *may or may not*
> affect other slices. I think would be more confusing overall.

Answer (score 0):

FYI : [are-slices-passed-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/570724)

> Everything in Go is passed by value, slices too. But a slice value is
> a header, describing a contiguous section of a backing array, and a
> slice value only contains a pointer to the array where the elements
> are actually stored. The slice value does not include its elements
> (unlike arrays).
>
> So when you pass a slice to a function, a copy will be made from this
> header, including the pointer, which will point to the same backing
> array. Modifying the elements of the slice implies modifying the
> elements of the backing array, and so all slices which share the same
> backing array will "observe" the change.
>
> To see what's in a slice header, check out the `reflect.SliceHeader`
> type:
>
> ```
> type SliceHeader struct {
>     Data uintptr
>     Len  int
>     Cap  int
> }
> ```
>
> See related / possible duplicate question: [Are Golang function
> parameter passed as copy-on-write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995634/are-golang-function-parameter-passed-as-copy-on-write)
>
> Read blog post: [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)