# Why does the specified object be eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

For the record, I'm **NOT** a Java Beginner, but -- rather -  an intermediate-level guy who kinda forgot a bit about fundamentals about Java.

```
class C{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        C c1=new C();
        C c2=m1(c1);        //line 4
        C c3=new C();
        c2=c3;              // line 6
        anothermethod();
    }
    static C m1(C ob1){
        ob1 =new C();      // line 10
        return ob1;
    }
    void anothermethod(){}
}
```

From the above code:

- Why is it that after line 6, 2 objects of type `C` are eligible for Garbage Collection(GC)?
- Why isn't it that in line 4 and line 10, a *copy* of `c1` is passed into the `m1()` method. So, eventually in line 6, there is going to be 1 Object (not 2) that are going to be eligible for GC. After all, isn't java pass -by-value rather than pass-by-reference?

Comment: this code should not compile: `anothermethod` is not static but being called in a static context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think two objects of type `C` are available for GC after line 6? I only see one (`c2`). What tool are you using that tells you otherwise?

Regarding your question about passing `c1` into your `m1` method: What you pass (by value) is a reference to the object -- a handle by which you can grab the object, if you will -- not a copy of it. The fact you pass a reference into `m1` is completely irrelevant, in fact -- you never use that reference, you immediately overwrite it with a reference to a new object, which you then return (this does not affect the `c1` that is still referenced in `main`).

Comment: Refer to question 13 in the following link: http://www.examsguide.com/scjp/freequestions2.html

Comment: @Catfish: We're not the only ones who think they're wrong: http://www.coderanch.com/t/452512/Programmer-Certification-SCJP/certification/help-garbage-collection

Comment: @Catfish: With respect to them, they're wrong. As of Line 6 in your code (and it looks about the same as theirs), the first C created (by main) is still referenced as c1 in main; the second C created (by m1) is no longer referenced (because the variable that was referencing it is no referencing the third one) and may be GC'd; the third instance created (by main) is still referenced by both `c2` and `c3` in `main`. Thus, the second object is the only one ready for GC. At least (the only one mentioned in that code). Apologies if you read my earlier breakdown, I got my `c2` and `c3` mixed up. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between pass-references-by-value and pass-values-by-reference :)

[Is Java Pass By Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) 
[Java is never pass by reference right right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795160/java-is-never-pass-by-reference-right-right) 
[Pass By Reference Or Pass By Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027/pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/2028#2028)

You might want to check out Jon Skeet's article on C# parameter-passing semantics as well, seeing as it's his favorite 'programmer ignorance' pet peeve: 
[What's your favorite 'programmer ignorance' pet peeve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/423833#423833).

So basically, I see your code do the following:

```
c1 = new C("Alice");
    // m1(C obj1) {     -- c1 gets passed to m1, a copy of the reference is made.
    //                  -- there are now two references to Alice (c1, obj1)
    //    obj1 = new C("Bob"); -- there is now one reference to Alice
                                // and one reference to Bob
    //    return obj1;  -- returns a reference to Bob(c1 still reference Alice)
    // }                -- when m1 returns, one of the references to Alice disappears.
c2 = m1(c1); // c2 points to Bob 
c3 = new C("Charlie");
c2 = c3;      // <-- Bob is eligible for collection. 
              // There are now two references to Charlie
```